# Как сделать AR на Unity 2019+

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, ar, vuforia

Нужно сделать AR что-бы люди могли просматривать его из дома, ImageTarget не подходит, в новых выпусках вуфории вырезан юзер дефайнд таргет, в старых на Unity 2019-2020 почему-то фпс проседает и странные глюки с камерой иногда, на unity 2019-2020 8th wall так же не работает, либо черный экран либо работает но изряда вон плохо (это даже о example сцене речь), как быть?  ARcore  поддерживает не так много устройств, Arkit только для Ios, а хочется что-то кросмплотформенное.

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы хотите реализовать"Нужно сделать AR что-бы люди могли просматривать его из дома" что просматривать?

Answer (score 0):

Я использую Unity 2019.4.16f1 и стабильную версию Vuforia 8.1.12 (на январь 2021), и все работает безотказно, если следовать такой последовательности действий:

1. Создать новый проект в Unity.
2. Через Windows -> Package Mаnager установить Vuforia Engine AR (стабильная версия 8.1.12)
3. Создать лицензионный ключ для своего проекта ([на официальном сайте](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Vuforia-License-Manager.html)).
4. В окне Hierarchy удалить объект Main Camera, добавить Vuforia Engine -> AR Camera.
5. В настройках AR камеры в Vuforia Configuration ввести созданный лицензионный ключ.
6. Создать Vuforia Engine -> Cloud Image -> Cloud Recognition и Vuforia Engine -> Cloud Image -> Image Target.
7. Создать облачную базу данных Cloud Database [по инструкции](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Work-with-Cloud-Databases.html).
8. В Cloud Recognition вставить ключи созданной базы данных.
9. Создать и добавить к Cloud Recognition скрипт SimpleCloudHandler с кодом:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;
    
public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, IObjectRecoEventHandler {
     
    private CloudRecoBehaviour mCloudRecoBehaviour;

    void Start()
    {
    mCloudRecoBehaviour = GetComponent();

    if (mCloudRecoBehaviour)
    {
        mCloudRecoBehaviour.RegisterEventHandler(this);
    }
    mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = true;
    }

    public void OnInitialized(TargetFinder targetFinder)
    {
        Debug.Log("Инициализировано Cloud Reco");
    }

    public void OnInitError(TargetFinder.InitState initError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ошибка инициализации Cloud Reco " + initError.ToString());
    }

    public void OnUpdateError(TargetFinder.UpdateState updateError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ошибка обновления Cloud Reco " + updateError.ToString());
    }

    public void OnStateChanged(bool scanning)
    {
        if (scanning)
        {
            ObjectTracker tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker();
            tracker.GetTargetFinder().ClearTrackables(false);
        }
    }

    public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
    {
    TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult cloudRecoSearchResult = (TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult)targetSearchResult;

    string nameOfTarget = cloudRecoSearchResult.TargetName;
    string metadataOfTarget = cloudRecoSearchResult.MetaData;

    //Используйте эти данные, как вам нужно, например, создайте элемент UI Text и выведите на экран название распознанного объекта
    }
}
```